# Format UTD date/time as MM/DD

Tags: excel

Trying to use Excel and I have a bunch of dates in a column that are formatted as below:

`Tue Sep 08 08:07:41 UTC 2015`

Excel doesn't seem to like this 'date' formatting and I'm only really interested in getting MM/DD.

I attempted to 'format cells' and using a custom date but that doesn't appear to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be 'only really interested in getting MM/DD'. Get the entire date as a true date value and format it as `mm/dd`.

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A2,5,6)&", "&RIGHT(A2,4))
```